# Finding links fast: regex vs. lxml

Tags: python, regex, html-parsing, web-crawler, lxml

I am trying to build a fast web crawler, and as a result, I need an efficient way to locate all the links on a page. What is the performance comparison between a fast XML/HTML parser like lxml and using regex matching?

Answer (score 7):

The problem here isn't about regex vs lxml. Regex just isn't a solution. How would you restrict the elements from where the links come from? A more real-world example is malformed HTML. How would you extract the contents of the `href` attribute out of this link?

```
<A href = /text" data-href='foo>' >Test</a>
```

lxml parses it just fine, just like Chrome, but good luck getting a regex to work.  If you're curious about the actual speed differences, here's a quick test I made.

**Setup:**

```
import re
import lxml.html

def test_lxml(html):
    root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
    #root.make_links_absolute('http://stackoverflow.com/')

    for href in root.xpath('//a/@href'):
        yield href

LINK_REGEX = re.compile(r'href="(.*?)"')

def test_regex(html):
    for href in LINK_REGEX.finditer(html):
        yield href.group(1)
```

**Test HTML:**

```
html = requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com/questions?pagesize=50').text
```

**Results:**

```
In [22]: %timeit list(test_lxml(html))
100 loops, best of 3: 9.05 ms per loop

In [23]: %timeit list(test_regex(html))
1000 loops, best of 3: 582 us per loop

In [24]: len(list(test_lxml(html)))
Out[24]: 412

In [25]: len(list(test_regex(html)))
Out[25]: 416
```

For comparison, here's how many links Chrome picks out:

```
> document.querySelectorAll('a[href]').length
413
```

Also, just for the record, [Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/) is one of the best web scraping frameworks out there and it uses lxml to parse the HTML.

Comment: Well, sometimes is more about built-in or not features. The html sample you gave (<A href = /text" data-href='foo>' >Test</a>) is not so much realistic (or i wanna think that...). Thanks you much for show the speed test.

Comment: @erm3nda: I've encountered broken HTML many times. Multiple closing `</body>` tags, unclosed quotes, etc. Browsers usually interpret the broken HTML as the author intended so they never fix their mistake, but strict HTML parsers aren't able to.

Answer (score -2):

You can use pyquery, a library for python that bring you functions from jquery.